# GoogleApiClient not making callbacks consistently when used by Service started on boot

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client, android-service-binding, google-location-services

The `Android` app I am working on has two services- `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, where the former starts the latter. `ServiceB` uses [GoogleAPIClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) to receive and provide location as intents to `ServiceA` and other clients.

I am trying to use GoogleAPIClient to get location on `ServiceB` like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ServiceB.this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mOnConnectionFailedListener)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

There are two scenarios on how `ServiceA` starts to later start `ServiceB`:

1. [Bound](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and started by the Activity.

   ```
   Intent serviceA = new Intent(context, ServiceA.class);
   bindService(serviceA, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   ```
2. On boot, through a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED .

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Intent serviceA = new Intent(context, ServiceA.class);
       startWakefulService(context, serviceA);
   }
   ```

After starting, `ServiceA` starts `ServiceB` like this:

```
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(ServiceA.this, ServiceB.class);
    startService(startIntent);
```

In both cases ServiceA and ServiceB are started.

Everything works well for case 1 (starting from `Activity`), but when using case 2 (starting on boot), after ServiceB starts and calls `mGoogleApiClient.connect()`, there is no notification to `mOnConnectionFailedListener` and `mConnectionCallbacks`, even after waiting for several minutes.

I don't understand what is the difference between the two cases that makes `GoogleAPIClient` ultimately not work, but I suspect it has something to do with the Context used to start `ServiceA`, as it is an `Activity` on case 1 and a `Context` provided on the `BroadcastReceiver` on case 2.

I need help in fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE 1**

I'm using Google Play Services version 8.4.0

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

**UPDATE 2**

After changed to version 9.2.1 there are still no callbacks.